# How to add the sum of cubes using a function in python?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, sum, cubes

I can get the answer of cubes but I don't really know where to go from here to get the function to return back the answer and keep adding it to a sum! What do I have to do to make it keep adding to get a total?

```
def sumNCubes(n):
    for i in range(n)
    return (n-1)**3
def main():
    number = int(raw_input("What number do you want to find the sum of cubes for?"))
    n = number + 1
    for i in range(number):
        n = n - 1 
    print "The result of the sums is:", sumNCubes(n)
main()
```

Comment: There must be a colon after your `for` loop. Please fix that.

Comment: @BhargavRao as much as I agree with you, I think you'l agree when I say thats not the only thing thing that needs changing :

Comment: @RNar Absolutely. There's more in there. Else I would have written an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do something like this:

```
def sumNCubes(n):
    return sum(i**3 for i in range(1,n+1))
```

which uses a list comprehension to cube number in a range from 1-n+1 (1-n will not include n) then uses python built in `sum` function to sum all of the cubes.

you could then just pass in your input and print it:

```
def main():
    number = int(raw_input("What number do you want to find the sum of cubes for?"))
    #this doesn't do anything but change n to 0
    #for i in range(number):
    #    n = n - 1 
    print "The result of the sums is:", sumNCubes(number)
main()
```

with input of, for example, `5`, this will return:

```
>>> sumNCubes(5)
225
```

Comment: Thanks! so the for loop was messing me up the whole time haha

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple. This will be given by recursive approach.

Here is the function to find sum of N numbers and *you were very close in getting this*

```
def sumNcubes(n):
  if (n == 1):
    return 1
  else:
    return n**3 + sumNcubes(n-1)

>>>sumNcubes(6)
441
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using n**3

```
def sum_cubes (n):
    b, c, sum = 1, 0, 0
    for a in range(0, 6*n, 6):
        sum += (c := c + (b := b + a))
    return sum
```

Without a loop

```
 def sum_cubes (n):
     return (n*(n+1)//2)**2
```